# Cookie Clicker Game

Tags: swift, ios

I'm getting into Swift iOS development, and decided to create a [Cookie Clicker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_Clicker) application as a first attempt. Since I am very new with Swift, I would like feedback and criticism on everything possible, to kick bad habits to the curb early. Any and all feedback is welcome, appreciated and considered!

*Since all of the code that I wrote is contained in the `ViewController` class, I'm only posting the class. If needed, I can post other classes. A screenshot of the layout of my app will also be available below.*

**ViewController.swift**

```
//MARK: Import Statements
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties

    //Labels

    @IBOutlet weak var cookiesPerClick: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfCookies: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainCookie: UILabel!

    //Buttons

    @IBOutlet weak var upgradeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cookieButton: UIButton!

    //Cookie Stuff

    var cookies: Int = 0
    var cookiesAClick: Int = 1
    var cookieUpgradeCost: Int = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        formatItems()
    }

    //MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func upgradeClicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (cookies >= cookieUpgradeCost) {
            cookiesAClick += 1
            cookies -= cookieUpgradeCost
            cookieUpgradeCost *= 2
            upgradeButton.setTitle(
                "Upgrade Cookie | Cost: \(cookieUpgradeCost) Cookies",
                for: .normal
            )
            numberOfCookies.text = "\(cookies)"
            cookiesPerClick.text = "Cookie Per Click: \(cookiesAClick)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func getCookie(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cookies += cookiesAClick
        numberOfCookies.text = "\(cookies)"
    }

    //MARK: Local Functions

    func formatItems() {
        //Upgrade Button Formatting
        upgradeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        upgradeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        upgradeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        //Get Cookie Button Formatting
        cookieButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cookieButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cookieButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        //Number Of Cookies Label Formatting
        numberOfCookies.layer.borderWidth = 1
        numberOfCookies.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        numberOfCookies.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        //Set main cookie to bold
        mainCookie.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35.0)

    }

}
```

**App Layout Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of app layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there isn't much code there are only few things that can be improved and all of them are styling:

- when working with outlets, make sure to specify the outlet type in the property name.
  ex. `cookiesPerClick` -> `cookiesPerClickLabel`
  Same applies for the `@IBAction`. Common approach is to add `buttonTapped` at the end `getCookieButtonTapped`. A bit more android way is `onAction` but still acceptable

The main reason for adding those suffixes is to make it clear what are you dealing with (button action, property label or whatever)

- I would rename `cookies` to `cookiesCount`. `cookies` sounds more like list of cookies
- delete generated comments like `// Do any additional setup after loading the view.`
- If you are not gonna expose some properties/functions (`cookies`, `cookiesAClick`, `cookieUpgradeCost`, `func formatItems()`) mark them as `private`
- In general an "early return" strategy is preferred where applicable as opposed to nesting code in if statements. Using guard statements for this use-case is often helpful and can improve the readability of the code

```
@@IBAction func upgradeClicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
            guard cookies < cookieUpgradeCost else { return }

            cookiesAClick += 1
            ...
        }
```

- You have three different views in `formatItems` that are styled the same way so it will be easier to maintain (and less code) to just separate the styling. I would add it in extension of `UIView`

```
extension UIView {
    func addBorder() {
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
```

and in `private func formatItems()` you will only have:

```
private func formatItems() {
    upgradeButton.addBorder()
    cookieButton.addBorder()
    numberOfCookies.addBorder()

    //Set main cookie to bold
    mainCookie.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 35.0)
}
```

Naming conventions are a bit optional since most of the companies have their own (or don't have at all) but you can find some official style guides

- [LinkedIn's Official Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide#311-using-guard-statements)
- [The official Swift style guide for raywenderlich.com](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)
- they both start with [Apple's API Design Guidelines.](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)